# Extracting and importing data in QTP

Tags: xml-parsing, qtp, xls

I have some work which requires extracting data from an XML file using Quick Test Professional and then importing it to an Excel sheet. I have searched the web and found the code to extract data but there seems to be no way to import the same to Excel.

Comment: It would probably help if you can show a sample of the XML data, the format you are presently able to convert it to, and what you have found in your research about the file formats that Excel can import. Can you convert the XML to CSV, for example?

Comment: If you can read the data from the XML already, why not just use QTP's built in `Datatable` commands to write it into Excel files and save them?